# Git repository replacing svn for Scratchbox build?

Tags: mono

I'm trying to follow the instructions at [the Mono Scratchbox page](http://www.mono-project.com/Scratchbox) at http://www.mono-project.com/Scratchbox

On of the steps under the :Installing The Devkit" section says to enter the following into Scratchbox:

```
svn co svn://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/trunk/release/garmono
```

This throws an error complaining that the repository does not exist. I did a search and could not find a specific reference, but it seems that the repository has moved to Git. Can anyone point me to the correct Git code set to pull down?

Thank you.

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: https://github.com/mono/release/tree/master/garmono

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mono/release
```

Then from there you should be able to pick back up at:

```
$ cd tree/master/garmono
$ make clean
... etc
```

Gl,
Aaron

Comment: Thank you Aaron. When I try to run git clone https://github.com/mono/release/tree/master/garmono I get an error "Cannot get remote repository information. Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?". I had to go right up the tree to "git clone https://github.com/mono/release" which I'm doing now. Hopefully I can then just pull the Garmono bit out. I'm a Linux noob - I've been doing Windows Embedded Compact for years, but am trying to use Linux Angstrom & Mono after being hassled for years to try Embedded Linux. Very frustrating so far, lots of bruises on my forehead...

Comment: You are right. My brain was in `svn` mode there :) You need to `clone` the root of the repo in git, whereas in svn you could checkout nested folders. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It got me to the next problem!